# error C2797 : list initialization inside member initializer list

Tags: c++, visual-studio, inheritance, visual-studio-2013

I was watching [MVA's tutorial on C++](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/c-a-general-purpose-language-and-library-jump-start-8251?l=rJ8ulRKy_5104984382) and the code I'm mentioning below is written by Kate not me. However she seems to get around with it without compiling showing any error but in my case I get the following error:

> Error 1   error C2797: 'NamedRectangle::_name': list initialization
>   inside member initializer list or non-static data member initializer
>   is not implemented    c:\users\abhimanyuaryan\documents\visual studio
>   2013\projects\kate demos\17
>   inheritance\inheritance\namedrectangle.h  12  1   Inheritance

Line 12 in the code is from my `NameRectangle` class which inherits from `Rectangle` class:

```
class NamedRectangle :  public Rectangle
{
public:
    NamedRectangle() { }

    NamedRectangle(std::string initial_name, int initial_width, int initial_height)
        : Rectangle{ initial_width, initial_height }, _name{ initial_name } //--> This line
    {}  

std::string get_name() const { return _name; }

private:
    std::string _name;

};
```

when I remove `std::string` initial_name from constructor as well as `_name{initial_name}` the code compiles. Please explain me with not taking me as a higher standard experienced programmer. I started C++ yesterday only.

Comment: not a duplicate: this code isn't about vectors and besides that's just been closed as a dupe of a more general "C++ 11 support in Visual Studio" question

Comment: I think you need round paranthesis ( ) instead of curly braces { } when calling the constructors for Rectangle() and _name().

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There was a compiler change between the time James and I wrote the code we used for the MVA day and today. What's happening is that

```
 _name{ initial_name }
```

is being interpreted as creating an initializer-list with one item in it and using that to initialize the member variable. Which you can't do.

The fix is to switch to round brackets:

```
 _name(initial_name)
```

This is causing confusion for a number of people and I have at least one client for whom this broke working code.

Comment: That answer and example is very important because I have used the '{}' for the variables in initializer list.

However, that '{}' only works when it is a single variable.

To deal with a collection of data or multiple items, like std::string (array of char) and std::vector, you have to use the '()'

Answer (score 13):

**tl;dr**: The solution in Kate's answer worked for the OP; the explanation is incorrect.  The code in question is actually correct and does compile in VS2015.  The error (in VS2013 *Update 3*) is a consequence of how MS handled a bug that was uncovered in VS2013 RTM (they didn't actually fix it with an update, but they did break some working code).  It is fixed correctly in VS2015.

---

Your code works fine in VS2015.  [According to Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/938122/), in VS2013,

> Yes, we inserted these errors into the compiler in Update 3 because our implementation of non-static data member initialization was incomplete.

List/braced initialization in a member initialization list is also broken in VS2013.  The problem with their implementation is [illustrated best](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn793970.aspx) with a `vector`, which has an `initializer_list` constructor that **should** greedily match any initialization that uses braces with convertable arguments, but it fails to do so:

```
struct S {
    S() : v1{1} {} // C2797, VS2013 RTM incorrectly calls 'vector(size_type)'

    std::vector<int> v1;
    std::vector<int> v2{1, 2}; // C2797, VS2013 RTM incorrectly calls 
                               // 'vector(size_type, const int &)'
};
```

The compiler too readily falls back to normal overload resolution.  Instead of using the `std::initializer_list` constructor, it calls the `size_t` constructor.  As their comments indicate, this is wrong!  So, because of their flawed implementation, Microsoft decided to disable the ability to use braced initialization in this context.

For a `std::string s`, there should be no issue because the right thing for `s{"duh"}` **is** to call `std::string(const char*)`, but because of the flaw, MS gives an error anyway.  The workaround is to explicitly use parenthesis in place of braces (or upgrade to VS2015), as stated in Kate's answer.  But the correct reason for the error is as stated above.

This applies to Non-Static Data Member Initialization (NSDMI) as well as to initialization lists.  This is explained more in this [Visual C++ Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/08/19/the-future-of-non-static-data-member-initialization.aspx). As for why VS2013 never got fixed:

> We originally planned to fix this bug in an update to Visual Studio 2013, but from an engineering perspective, the right thing to do is to avoid another kludge and thoroughly address the handling of initialization. But overhauling compiler architecture is a massive task due to the amount of fundamental code that needs to be modified. We could not risk creating incompatibilities or large bug tails in an update, so a correct implementation of NSDMI could only be shipped in a major release.

Apparently, the fix made it into Visual Studio 2015, but will never be in an update to 2013.

Answer (score -4):

I solve it.

```
class Namedrectangle : public Rectan
{
    public:
    Namedrectangle(){}

    Namedrectangle(string intname, int init_width, int init_height) 
         : Rectan{ init_width, init_height }
    {
        this->_name=intname;************
    }

    string get_name() const
    {
        return _name;
    }

    private:
    string _name;
};
```

I think İt can't initialize because variable can't find or load